# ¿Como puedo solucionar el error de un metodo polimorfico cuando en una clase hijo funciona bien y en la otra no?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

El error que me sale es el siguiente System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

La duda que tengo es en donde me estoy equivocando.

Clase padre con el método:

```
public abstract void Pagar_cuota(double valor, double cuotas);
```

Clase hijo#1 con el método:

```
public override void Pagar_cuota(double valor, double cuotas)
{
   valor = valor + (valor * 0.015);            
   ValorCuota = valor;
}
```

Clase hijo#2 con el metodo:

```
public override void Pagar_cuota(double valor, double cuotas)
{
   valor = (valor+(valor * 0.2553)) / cuotas;
   ValorCuota = valor;
}
```

Invocacion del método a la clase main:

```
//Aquí cuando invoco el método con el segundo hijo me sale el error de 
//la pregunta, pero si lo invoco por ejemplo 
//hipotecario.Pagar_cuota(monto_cuota, cuotas); funciona correctamente
                
libreinversion.Pagar_cuota(monto_cuota, cuotas);

Console.WriteLine("El valor de cada cuota es: " + libreinversion.ValorCuota);

libreinversion.Valor = libreinversion.Valor - 
libreinversion.ValorCuota;

Console.WriteLine("El valor es: " + libreinversion.Valor);
```

Comment: El error sucede cuando intentas acceder a un miembro de una variable establecida en `null`.  Es posible que `libreinversion` sea `null`. Te aconsejo que debugees el programa y veas en qué línea ocurre o pases el error completo.